# Why C++ try/catch does not catch the "pure virtual call" exception?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, com

The following function is compiled in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. In this function, `CAttributedObject` is a COM class implementing the `IObjectID` interface. The function must process notification about an event. Parameter `pCaller` is a pointer to an object of type `CAttributedObject`, which was the source of the event. The notification is dispatched to the main thread through its message queue. It is expected that by the moment the notification arrives, the object pointed by `pCaller` can be destroyed; this is why try/catch blocks are present in the code.

Sometimes, however, the call to `QueryInterface` raises a "pure virtual call" exception, which is not caught and causes the application to crash. There are many other cases where we test access to potentially deleted memory with try/catch, and the all has worked for years. I do not understand why "pure virtual call" exception is special.

```
HRESULT CDataProvider::OnObjIconChanged(
            BSTR Key, BSTR Path, IUnknown* pCaller,
            UINT Flags, __int64 hIcon, const CLSID& ProviderCLSID)
{
    CAttributedObject* pAttrObj = 0;
    IObjectID* pObjID = 0;
    try {
        try { pCaller->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IObjectID), (void**)&pObjID); }
        catch(...) {}

        if (pObjID != 0)
            pAttrObj = static_cast<CAttributedObject*>(pObjID);

        if (pAttrObj != 0)
        {
            pAttrObj->SetIcon((HICON)hIcon, Flags & SHGFI_SMALLICON);
            pAttrObj->Release();
        }
    } catch(...) {}

    TreeService()->Fire_ObjIconChanged(Key, Path, hIcon);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199037/discussion-on-question-by-ilia-why-c-try-catch-does-not-catch-the-pure-virtua).

Comment: " the object pointed by pCaller can be destroyed" Maybe you are missing `AddRef`/`Release` pair somewhere.

Comment: First mistake is calling it a "pure virtual call exception." "Pure virtual call" is not an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not understand why "pure virtual call" exception is special.

Because it is undefined behavior, according to the C++ standard. Undefined behavior that indicates a bug in your code, somewhere. Given that this is undefined behavior, a C++ implementation ***may*** throw a catchable exception, but it is not obligated to do so. Most C++ implementations log a terse message, and `abort()` the entire program.

The only time a pure virtual function call could possibly be made within the bounds of the C++ standard is from a constructor or destructor of the abstract base class, and the C++ standard explicitly states this to be undefined behavior:

> [class.abstract]
>
> Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of
>   an abstract class; the effect of making a virtual call to a pure
>   virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created
>   (or destroyed) from such a constructor (or destructor) is undefined.

There is no other possible way to make an pure virtual function call, since you cannot instantiate, directly, abstract classes (classes with pure virtual functions) in C++, this is further hashed out elsewhere in the same clause.

Therefore, no matter which way you turn, you end up with undefined behavior. You have a bug in your code, somewhere, that either results in a pure virtual function call from a constructor or destructor, or memory corruption. This must be addressed not by catching some exception, but by locating the bug and fixing it.

If it was required to throw a catchable exception in this situation, it wouldn't be undefined behavior, wouldn't it?

Exceptions are not undefined behavior. Their mechanical working parts are fully defined in the C++ standard.

Comment: *Because it is undefined behavior, according to the C++ standard* no, because current lib implementation of `_purecall` call `__fastfail()`, if `IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_FASTFAIL_AVAILABLE)` and this concrete exception can not be handled from application (only by debugger). if not present `PF_FASTFAIL_AVAILABLE` - the `STATUS_FATAL_APP_EXIT` exception generated, which can be handled. however all this is windows specific and depend from implementation of `_purecall`. not from generic *c++* standard

Comment: @Sam OK, thank you. Though the excerpt from the standard that you cited does not have any relation to my case, I now understand that the "pure virtual call" exception IS special.